# UIPageViewController show view following device size. how to force it to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib, uipageviewcontroller

I implemented 3 container view which will be fill with page view like photo below
[image]
[image]
[image]

but when I install it in iphone the last one in the below following the size of the device so it become smaller. why is that like that? I tried to make a width to make it fix but still nothing change. is anyone know how to do this? Thank you for the answer

this is in the app
[image]

Comment: Could you click on articles containerView and show us your constraints? Also show us that PageViews constraints as well

Comment: done, I already send more image @OneCommentMan

Answer (score -1):

found the solution by adding this line of code in my view controller that used as an image in UIPageViewController

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

Comment: If you want to force a UIPageViewController to display a fixed view size regardless of the device size, you can adjust its view property directly. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:


// Create a custom view size
let fixedViewSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 400)

// Create an instance of UIPageViewController
let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)

// Set the initial view controller using your custom size
pageViewController.setViewControllers([initialViewController], direction: .forward, animated: tru